# Prove that determinant of matrix equal to n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove that determinant of matrix $D_n$ (square $n$ x $n$ matrix) is equal to $n$.
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
1 & 1 & & & \\
1 & & 1 & & \\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \\
1 & & & & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

I tried to find some recurrence here when calculating using LaPlace expansion, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first column $C_1$, and replace it by $C_1-\sum_{j=2}^nC_j$. This column becomes $\pmatrix{n\\0\\\vdots\\0}$.